# Как добраться до элемента в XML файле. c#

Tags: c#, winforms, xml

Дан Xml файл. Мне нужно добраться до элемента "glava1" и далее перебирать уже остальные элементы. Как это выполнить? В дальнейшем мне так же нужен доступ до следующих элементов.
Xml файл:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<catalog>
    <book name="book1">
        <glava name ="glava1">
            <zagolovok>Заголовок 1</zagolovok>
            <text>Некоторый текст 1</text>
           <kompilator>Другой текст 1</kompilator>
    </glava>
    <test name ="test1">
        <vopros>Вопрос</vopros>
        <otvet>ответ1</otvet>
        <otvet>ответ2</otvet>
        <otvet>ответ3</otvet>
    </test>
    <glava name ="glava2">
        <zagolovok>Заголовок 2</zagolovok>
        <text>Текст 2</text>
        <kompilator>другой 2</kompilator>
    </glava>
    <test name ="test2">
        <vopros>Вопрос 2</vopros>
        <otvet>ответ 1</otvet>
        <otvet>ответ 2</otvet>
        <otvet>ответ 3</otvet>
    </test>
</book>
</catalog>
```

Мне удалось добраться до элемента "book1" а как дальше
c# WinForms:

```
    void GetText()
    {
        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xDoc.Load("C:\\Project\\Visual Studio\\xmlfile\\xmlfile\\XMLFile1.xml");
        // получим корневой элемент
        XmlElement xRoot = xDoc.DocumentElement;
        if (xRoot != null)
        {
            // обход всех узлов в корневом элементе
            foreach (XmlElement xnode in xRoot)
            {
                // получаем атрибут name
                XmlNode attr = xnode.Attributes.GetNamedItem("name");
                
                // Какой то код дальше...
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При работе с XML лучше использовать **LINQ to XML** API.

Он доступен в .Net Framework с 2007 года.

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    const string filename = @"e:\Temp\Sherlock_201.xml";

    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(filename);

    var glava = xdoc.Descendants("glava")
        .Where(x => x.Attribute("name").Value.Equals("glava1")); 

    Console.WriteLine(glava);
    
    foreach (var elem in glava.Elements())
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{elem.Name}='{elem.Value}'");
    }
}
```

**Результат**

```
<glava name="glava1">
  <zagolovok>Заголовок 1</zagolovok>
  <text>Некоторый текст 1</text>
  <kompilator>Другой текст 1</kompilator>
</glava>

zagolovok='Заголовок 1'
text='Некоторый текст 1'
kompilator='Другой текст 1'
```

Comment: вместо `.Value` лучше использовать приведение типа, потому что оно безопасно для null: `(string)x.Attribute("name") == "glava1"`

Comment: Спасибо! Очень помогли!